# He and I are similar in that

Tags: grammar

How do you say this in Japanese:

"Takeshi and I are similar in that we both have 'May sickness.'"

Here's my best guess:
私は、たけしが「五月病」というものがあるという点で似ています。

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> 「 [私]{わたし}は、たけし**が**『[五月病]{ごがつびょう}』というものがあるという[点]{てん}で[似]{に}ています。」

This is certainly a good try, but it is missing something.   As usual, it is the particle choice.  If you used 「私は～～～～似ている」, native speakers would expect to see/hear the particle 「に」, and not 「が」.

> 「(Person or Thing) + **に**（or と） + 似ている」
>
> = "to be similar ***to*** ~~"

Thus, by using as much as you used, the correct sentence would be:

> 「私は、『五月病』というものがあるという点で、たけし**に**似ています。」

To avoid sounding wordy for using 「という」 twice, I would recommend the following.

> 「私は、『五月病』があるという点で、たけしに似ています。」

Other correct sentences include:

> 「たけしと私**は**、『五月病』があるという点で似ています。」
>
> 「『五月病』があるという点で、私**は**たけし**に**（or **と**）似ています。」
>
> 「『五月病』があるという点で、私とたけし**は**似ています。」

Comment: 「5月病にかかっている」では?